# HowTo: Create a ror project that has Email/Password authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this possible out of the box with Rails? or is an add-on or hack required?

Comment: What rails version do you want to use?

Comment: I'm a newbie so I'm going with the stable version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible out of the box, but you can install one gem and get any authentication system you want.

1. [RESTful authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication);
2. [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic);
3. [Devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

And so forth. There are many solutions to solve your task. Just choose one.

Comment: Any recommendations? I'm a day 1 newbie moving from ColdFusion.

Comment: I recommend you to watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication and http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication to get the idea about how to deal with those plugins. It's very easy! Just install one of them and generate some stuff (you can use screencasts, step-by-step guides, tutorials).